# Vercel ignore build step according to folder of committed files

Tags: vercel

i'm using vercel's ignore build step field to disable preview deploys (IE - only deploy if the branch is main)

I'm doing this with the following bash script:

```
if [[ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" == "main" ]] ; then
  # Proceed with the build
    echo "✅ - Build can proceed"
  exit 1;
else
  # Don't build
  echo " - Build canceled"
  exit 0;
fi
```

Now, another requirement I have is to only deploy if the changed files belong to a specific folder. Can I somehow combine these two requirements in the same script?
How do I access the paths of the committed files in this bash script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Vercel has added some docs that address [this exact situation](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel#with-folders-and-workspaces:):

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --quiet ./packages/frontend/
```

> If changes were commited to `./packages/frontend/`, the command will yield a non-empty response, allowing the build to proceed.

I also use a similar setup, but call a node script ([check it out here](https://gist.github.com/tknickman/bc63ec30bec6366e1552ff8a37299db5)) as my `Ignored Build Step` option.

Comment: warning. this command does not work when pushing multiple commits.